# Using dry yeast in a yeast starter

Tags: yeast

I've read different opinions on this, but I wanted to try a starter because my recent brews have not gone that well. Is it advantageous to do a starter, assuming rehydration first, with dry yeast, or is it of little benefit?

Comment: What are your particular reasons for wanting to do a starter with dried yeast? Pitching rate is not normally an issue with dried yeast compared to liquid yeast cell counts, so wondering what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Also, what problems do you want to avoid? What beer are you brewing (OG, expected FG)?

Comment: why not, give it a try and see. just don't let it go for more than 12 hours before you pitch so the yeast won't feed out!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yeast starter's goal is multiplying yeast cells so they do not have too difficult job eating through all the sugar in your wort. It is recommended to do them while using liquid yeast because they are more delicate and die much faster than dried version, thus reducing the cell count and lowering your fermentation parameters. Dry yeast does not need to be multiplied over its packet numbers in normal circumstances.

Having said that, it would be useful to make a starter with dry yeast in case of higher gravity beers. It is recommended to use more than one packet of dry yeast for gravity from about 18 Blg (~1.074 OG), but you can multiply cells from one packet in a starter to get similar result.

Comment: If you are brewing a bigger beer, and using dry yeast, just use more yeast. The time, effort and risk of a starter is a little absurd compared with the cost of dry yeast.

Comment: That's what I'm saying too. There is a possibility to make a starter for this reason, it is not reasonable in my opinion as well.

Comment: That depends on who you can buy yeast from. My LHBS charges about 8 bucks for a sachet of dried yeast, or 4 bucks for enough DME for 5 1l starters. I brew 50l batches, so I always do a starter for my dry yeast. It's even cheaper if you save a little wort from previous brews for your starter.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it not necessary nor recommended to do a starter with dry yeast.  If you tell us the problems you're trying to avoid we may be able to help diagnose them.

Comment: First batch was normal OG and seemed to go well except for bottle conditioning.  Second batch Wes higher gravity (about 1.072) and only got down to 1.024. Target was 1.016. Bottle conditioning was almost without carbonation.  I've read that yeast starters improve the quality and are needed for higher gravity beers.  Now I am hearing there is no benefit fif using dry yeast and if it's a high gravity it's better to use a second packet.  If I don't have a second packet is there any advantage to doing a starter?

Comment: @LeeE Please edit your question to provide additional information and to clarify. Comments are not meant for discussion. Others may not even see them when they try to answer your question without digging through all the existing answers.

Comment: Yeast starters are really only needed for liquid yeast that doesn't have enough cells to ferment your wort. I'm new at brewing myself, and in my limited experience, I had a similar problem not long ago. Starting gravity was 1.071 and ended up at around 1.024 because I didn't aerate enough, high temps, and yeast attenuation was too low. To lower my gravity, I used a dry yeast to make a yeast starter and pitched it into my already mostly fermented beer, because I wanted the yeast to be strong and healthy when I threw it into an already alcoholic environment. This got my gravity down to 1.018.